# "Error getting value from ReadTimeout" when creating DriveItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a new SharePoint DriveItem using the content of an existing DriveItem using the Microsoft Graph API. However, I am getting the error below when attempting to create the DriveItem. Can somebody explain why?

**Edit:** Simplified to use manually-created MemoryStream object

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphSDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
using (var docStream = new MemoryStream(1024))
{   
   var doc = new DriveItem
   {
        Content = docStream,
        Name = "00_newDoc.docx",
        ParentReference = new ItemReference
        {
            Id = "<folderId"
        }
    };
    var resultItem = await graphClient.Drives["<driveId>"].Items["<folderId>"].Request().CreateAsync(driveItem);
}
```

I can upload the file content directly with the following, but I then lose the ability to specify more metadata in the DriveItem in a single call.

```
var resultItem = await graphClient.Drives["<driveId>"].Items["<folderId>"].ItemWithPath("00_newDoc.docx").content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem(docStream);
```

**Error:**

> Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object&
>   memberValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty
>   member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty
>   containerProperty)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type
>   type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)    at
>   Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.SerializeObject(Object serializeableObject)
>   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__36.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__32`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Graph.DriveItemRequest.<CreateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Informa.eDocs.AzureFunctions.Functions.PostDocToSharePoint.d__0.MoveNext()

Inner Exception:

> Timeouts are not supported on this stream.    at
>   System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()    at GetReadTimeout(Object )    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object
>   target)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the issue is that you are encountering.

With that said, is there a reason for downloading the file stream only to upload it again as a new driveitem?

Have you considered using the copy functionality? It should work something like this (I haven't tried it yet):

```cs
// Copy item reference
ItemReference iRef = new ItemReference()
{
    DriveId = "b!ez3F6Nysf0yYklsI2gUdcx4e7pSsSDZClwfWe3rFh4mSiYpAIn5zRLcsEeS7g5dr",
    Id = "01YYVWN6F6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
};

// Copy it
await graphClient.Me.Drives["<driveId>"].Items["<ItemId>"].Copy("copiedItem.txt", iRef).Request().PostAsync();
```

**Update**

The API is not intended to be used this way. I don't know the reason why it can't be done in a single call. I do know that you must first create the item with a [POST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_post_children) (example shows a folder, but the idea is the same for a file), and then [PUT](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content) the content stream in a subsequent call.

Comment: I should have clarified--I am aware of the Copy functionality. This is only part of a POC to show that we can retrieve and upload using the graph API. My main concern is regarding why I am unable to create a new DriveItem in the way I've described.

Comment: The difference with a File is that it requires Content to be set, and this has to be a stream.  If this is not how the API is to be used then that should be explained.